# Got Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException on iOS 16 only

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, autolayout

I've gotten stuck at this firebase crashlytic report `CoreAutoLayout NSISLinExpReplaceVarWithVarPlusDelta`. While reading stack trace it seems like I suddenly perform autolayout update on background thread. But I am unable to find out where it's in the whole project. Btw, the report said 100% came from iOS 16, I wonder if there are any updates about autolayout on iOS 16. I've tried on both simulator and real device however, still can not reproduce this error. Does anyone know how to find/fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9cb4 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x183d0 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreAutoLayout                 0xde68 NSISLinExpReplaceVarWithVarPlusDelta
3  CoreAutoLayout                 0x4e40 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x43a8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
5  QuartzCore                     0x9f30 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
6  QuartzCore                     0x1d4ac CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
7  QuartzCore                     0x2e8d8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
8  QuartzCore                     0x5de80 CA::Transaction::commit()
9  QuartzCore                     0xa86d0 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*)
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b9c _pthread_tsd_cleanup
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4560 _pthread_exit
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc pthread_main_np
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe64 _pthread_wqthread
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb7c start_wqthread
```

From firebase exception:

```
Crashed: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1e2cc FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 393 (FIRCLSProcess.c:393)
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1e6ac FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 424 (FIRCLSProcess.c:424)
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1573c FIRCLSHandler + 34 (FIRCLSHandler.m:34)
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x10410 __FIRCLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 232 (FIRCLSException.mm:232)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x13428 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xf41c FIRCLSExceptionRecord + 234 (FIRCLSException.mm:234)
7  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xff30 FIRCLSExceptionRecordNSException + 126 (FIRCLSException.mm:126)
8  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xf074 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 398 (FIRCLSException.mm:398)
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x10fbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x13d34 __cxa_get_exception_ptr + 34
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x13ce0 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 138
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18530 objc_exception_throw + 412
13 CoreAutoLayout                 0xde68 NSISLinExpReplaceVarWithVarPlusDelta + 326
14 CoreAutoLayout                 0x4e40 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 36
15 UIKitCore                      0x43a8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1872
16 QuartzCore                     0x9f30 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500
17 QuartzCore                     0x1d4ac CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 148
18 QuartzCore                     0x2e8d8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 444
19 QuartzCore                     0x5de80 CA::Transaction::commit() + 648
20 QuartzCore                     0xa86d0 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 228
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b9c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 620
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4560 _pthread_exit + 84
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10cc pthread_main_np + 78
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe64 _pthread_wqthread + 424
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb7c start_wqthread + 8
```